# Starting a service from /etc/event.d works, but not from /etc/init

Tags: startup, scripts, upstart, 8.04

I'm trying to launch an upstart service on Ubuntu 8.04 from /etc/init/, but I always get start: Unknown job: job.  When I try to launch this script from /etc/event.d/ it works fine.  Why would this be and how would I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ubuntu 8.04 included an older version of Upstart, which stored its scripts under `/etc/event.d` rather than `/etc/init` like current versions do.

While upgrading Upstart would make it look in the new location, I would strongly recommend against doing that unless you are upgrading the entire system (e.g. to the current LTS release: 10.04).  Other packages designed for 8.04 that include Upstart scripts will expect that the `/etc/event.d` location is being used.

If you are stuck on 8.04, it is probably better to work with the version it ships with.

Comment: That's what I figured.  Thanks, it should be more obvious in the Upstart documentation or at least mentioned in the UbuntuBootupHowto.